# Jmeter "Load environment settings" gives Responsecode 500

Tags: jmeter

Got a JMeter-4.0-project that runs fine on colleagues' laptops, but not on mine. When I run the project, it halts in the Setup phase,

[image: -4.0enter image description here]

while trying to open the file load_environment_settings.bsh with this message:

> Response message: org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: source  Sourced file: C:\myprograms\apache-jmeter-4.0\bin\CBSPerfProj\trunk\moas..\includes\load_environment_settings.bsh : Typed variable declaration : Object constructor

The file load_environment_settings.bsh does exist and I do have full rights to that file. The entire structure, directory, and files is identical to my colleagues' structure.

Any ideas what can be wrong?

Comment: Does your version of Jmeter is same as your colleague's? And check java versions as well

Comment: Yep it was the same. Never solved this, since we now have our test-environment setup on a vm at aws. Lovely. No more setup issues. :-)